# jQuery goMap is overwriting the styles for my footer? How to stop?

Tags: jquery, css, google-maps, html

So this seems to be causing the issue .. http://www.pittss.lv/jquery/gomap/

Whenever I included this, my footer goes awry.

This is my code: http://jsbin.com/eroley/edit

The footer is css fixed position: absolute -- bottom:0 to the bottom of the page on every other page of the website except for the contact page where it wants to act as if it's fixed to the page (i.e. fixed to the bottom at all times over-top of content rather then at the very bottom of the page).

I've narrowed it down to this piece of code within gomap -

```
        navigationControlOptions: {
            position: 'TOP_LEFT',
            style: 'DEFAULT' /* <-- THIS IS WHAT IS CAUSING THE ISSUE */
        },
```

When I remove it, the footer is fine but the maps don't work, and visa-versa. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is it adding a DOM node which wraps the footer in some way? Remember `position:absolute;` is an absolute position relative to the node's parent, assuming the parent has a position other than static.